# Capture word before a specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a javascript regular expression that will capture the "word" that comes before a single or double `:`.

Here are some examples:

```
*, ::before, ::after // do not capture anything
.class1, .class2:before,.class3::after // captures .class2 and .class3
.class4::before // captures .class4
```

[This is what I have right now:](http://regex101.com/r/wU8uM7/3) `/(\S+?):/g`. It matches any non-white space character one to infinity times as few times as possible, then stops at a `:`.

This works except:

1. If there is no space before the "word", it captures too far.
2. It captures the first colon of `::before` and `::after`.

Comment: is there must be a word character before `:`? If yes, then you could use this `(\S+?\b):?:` http://regex101.com/r/wU8uM7/4

Comment: I'm sorry, I realized the link did not match the example I included .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
 ([.\w]+):?:\w+
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/wS7pV8/2)**

[image]

As you need, this regex does:

```
([.\w]+)      Captures alphanumeric and dots strings before
:?:\w+        one or two colons followed with some alphanumeric
```

Match information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [57-64] `.class2`
MATCH 2
1.  [72-79] `.class3`
MATCH 3
1.  [119-126]   `.class4`
```

Comment: What if I want to allow hyphens as well (i.e. not only alphanumeric and dots)? http://regex101.com/r/wS7pV8/3

Comment: @thetallweeks just add it to `[.\w]` like `[-.\w]`. Bear in mind that [] allows you to define a set of characters, so `[-.\w]` will allow `-`,`.`,`A-Za-z0-9_`

Comment: Ahhh! I misunderstood the `.` inside the `[]` before. Thank you.

Comment: I have learned that my test cases are too simple. Instead of just matching from the first word character or `.` to the first `:`, I need to essentially match from the `:` backward until a `,` or the start of the line. http://regex101.com/r/wS7pV8/9

Comment: @thetallweeks I see. That seems to be a more complex scope than what you posted in your question. You could achieve what you want using this regex http://regex101.com/r/wS7pV8/10. But this works for pcre regex. Maybe you can create a new question asking about this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add on an additional/optional `:` to the end:

```
/(\S+?)::?/g
```

Or you can specify this as a repetition 1-2 times:

```
/(\S+?):{1,2}/g
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/qT7nZ2/1)