# Capture text from a colon backward until a comma or start of line

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a javascript regular expression that will capture a css selector.

Here are some examples:

```
*, ::before, ::after // do not capture anything
::before // do not capture anything
.class1, .class2:before,.class3::after // capture .class2 and .class3
.class4::before // capture .class4
.class-5::before // capture .class-5
.class__6::after // capture .class__6
.class--7 > .child::after // capture .class--7 > .child
#id1 + .something:after // capture #id1 + .something
#id2[attribute-one="1"] + .class8:before // capture #id2[attribute-one="1"] + .class8
```

[Here is what I currently have](http://regex101.com/r/wS7pV8/15): `/([.#\-+~>\[\]\"\'=\w ]+)(?=:?:)/g`. This is not ideal because I essentially have to whitelist special characters.

Instead, I would rather do something like:

1. Find the colon
2. Go backwards until I hit a comma or start of line

Bonus points for ignoring lone whitespaces, so

```
*, ::before
```

would not capture the space after the comma.

*Note: This is essentially a more complex version of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918914/capture-word-before-a-specific-character)*

Comment: Have you considered using a [parser](http://glazman.org/JSCSSP/) instead of regexes?

Comment: I had not considered a parser, but I will look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:^|,)([^:,\n]+):
```

And **grab captured group #1** for your matches.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wS7pV8/16)

Comment: It looks like this captures the comma and the first colon as well. Is it possible to ignore them?

Comment: No that's not true, you need at captured group #1. Look at the matched group #1 on right-bottom side of the demo link.

Comment: Are you looking at the javascript regex? If so, I think the area that says "Match Information" is incorrect. I tested this in javascript code and am seeing the commas and colons included.

Comment: Yes the area under `MATCH INFORMATION` gives you matched groups and that is without `,` and `:` as you can also see.

Comment: Yes indeed it is `exec` that needs to be called in a loop to get all the matches from captured group#1.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!,\s*:),([^,:]+):|^(?!\s*:)([^,:]+):
```

Try this.It gives all the matches.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pD5sV6/1

Comment: I noticed this uses the pcre style, but with javascript regex it does not properly capture the matches

Comment: @thetallweeks groups were only for convenience.see http://regex101.com/r/pD5sV6/7

Comment: @thetallweeks also it does not capture the spaces in first two rows :)